# Linq with Regex

Tags: c#, linq

I have the matches of a regex pattern and I'm having some difficulties designing the Linq around it to produce the desired output.

The data is fixed lengths: `1231234512341234567`

Lengths in this case are: `3, 5, 4, 7`

The regex pattern used is: `(.{3})(.{5})(.{4})(.{7})`

This all works perfectly fine and the matched results of the pattern are as expected, however, the desired output is proving to be somewhat difficult.  In fact, I'm not even certain what it would be called in SQL terms - except maybe a pivot query.  The desired output is to take all the values from each of the groups at a given position and concatenate them so for example:

```
field1:value1;value2;value3;valueN;field2:value2;value3;valueN;
```

Using the below Linq expression, I was able to get field1-value1, field2-value2, etc...

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(data, re).Cast<Match>();

var xmlResults = from m in matches
                 from e in elements
                 select string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", e.Name, m.Groups[e.Ordinal].Value);
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to get all the values at position 1 from "Groups" using the element's Ordinal, then all the values at position 2 and so on.

The "elements" in this example is a collection of field names and ordinal positions (starting at 1). So, it would look like this:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }
}

var elements = new List<Element>{ 
    new Element { Name="Field1", Ordinal=1 },
    new Element { Name="Field2", Ordinal=2 }
};
```

I've reviewed a bunch of various Linq expressions and dug into some pivot type Linq expressions, but none of them get me close - they all use the join operator which I don't think is possible.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by changing the query to select from `elements` only, and bring in the `matches` through `string.Join`, like this:

```
// Use ToList to avoid iterating matches multiple times
var matches = Regex.Matches(data, re).Cast<Match>().ToList();
// For each element, join all matches, and pull in the value for e.Ordinal
var xmlResults = elements.Select(e => 
    string.Format(
        "<{0}>{1}</{0}>"
    ,   e.Name
    ,   string.Join(";", matches.Select(m => m.Groups[e.Ordinal].Value))
    );
```

Note: this is not the best way of formatting XML. You would be better off using one of .NET's libraries for making XML, such as LINQ2XML.

Comment: It's close - the first SelectMany appears to be on the right track, but how do I output the element name one time with many values after it?  Also note that I'm not outputting XML - it's a proprietary format.

Comment: @ChrisGessler If you do not want them in separate tags, you don't even need `SelectMany` - you can join them right away in a simple `Select` that uses `string.Format` and `string.Join` (see the update).